# To do ascending order in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

How to get this data in ascending order?

**Output =**

```
 GRN
 ------------------
 GRNV-1415-RESH-132
 GRNV-1415-RESH-13
 GRNV-1417-RESH-2
 GRNV-1415-RESH-8
 GRNV-1416-RESH-12
 GRNV-1411-RESH-1
 GRNV-1415-RESH-13
 GRNV-1415-RESH-99
```

My query is :

```
select GRN 
from tbl_receipt 
where Active = 1
  and ArticleContrasted = 1 
  and LocationID = 41  
order by 
   left(GRN, patindex('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', GRN)-1) asc
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.

You can get the number at the end using:

```
select right(grn, charindex('-', reverse(grn)) - 1)
```

Then, convert this to a number, so:

```
select left(grn, len(grn) - charindex('0', reverse(grn))),
       cast(right(grn, charindex('-', reverse(grn)) - 1) as int)
```